# Linux freezes after a cold start: "NVRM: GPU has fallen off the bus", Xid 79

Tags: nvidia, freeze, hang

Here my configuration:

- AMD Ryzen 9 7950X 16-Core
- Gigabyte X670E Aorus Master
- DDR5 Corsair Vengeance 5200 MHz 16 GB
- PNY Nvidia GeForce RTX 4080

I have a dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 23.04.
Windows runs fine.
Linux, *every* time I turn on the PC after a power cycle (i.e. a "cold boot"), hangs withing few minutes. Hang means the screen freezes on what I'm doing, nothing is responsive anymore - even the keyboard. I have to hardware reset the machine. Sometimes, after several minutes it reboots itself.

Once it has rebooted, I can work for the whole day without any other issue.
I tried to: turn on the PC, after login reboot. No way, *it has to freeze anyway*.

Other things I've already inspected:

- I had two DDR5 modules, but one was defective so I removed it. Anyway, the problems with the faulty one were different and happened on both Windows and Linux.
- tried to move the RAM module into the other slot (i.e. from A2 to B2)
- ran memtest86+ several times
- removed the proprietary drivers for the graphic card. Currently I'm using the default opensource xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (no GPU acceleration)
- tried to switch between xorg and wayland
- inspected some system logs (dmesg, syslog, xorg) but I didn't find anything relevant (at least to me!)
- updated to the latest packages versions
- reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch
- updated BIOS to the latest version
- added `pcie_aspm=off` kernel option

Does this description may help you to me on the right track?
What else can I do to find out the reason of the hangs? Where and what should I look for in the log files?

### UPDATE

Thanks to user Artem S. Tashkinov, I discovered that during those hangs the machine is still alive and accepts SSH connections.

`dmesg` clearly says the GPU is the culprit:

[image]

[Here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus/217357) I read it seems a bug of nvidia, since - like the user - 1. it happens no matter what I'm doing, even with no activity at all (hence no thermal/ps cause) 2. after the reboot it works fine the whole day 3. in Windows there are no issues at all.

Have I to live with it? Or is there a way to fix?

Comment: One thing I'd suggest (since you tried reinstalling from scratch as part of the troubleshooting) - try installing something that isn't Ubuntu or Ubuntu based. Or perhaps an older LTS Ubuntu (you didn't mention WHICH Ubuntu you installed). From casual observation, Ubuntu seems to increasingly suck recently

Comment: @JaromandaX I wrote Ubuntu 23.04, which other detail should I add? Perhaps I can try a live of another distro. But It would really a pain to actually install another distro now

Comment: Go back to proprietary NVIDIA drivers. Nouveau is known for this kind of stuff. Installing older versions of Ubuntu is ill-advised considering how fresh the system is. I'd also recommend updating BIOS to the latest version. And also try installing the latest kernel, Google for "Ubuntu install mainline kernel".

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, yes I installed nouveau just to test. But I'm running the latest nvidia drivers. Out of curiosity, if it was the BIOS it should not affect *any* OS?

Comment: Nope, buggy BIOSes for some reasons affect Linux more than Windows. Windows has roughly 100 times more users, so Microsoft has a lot more failsafes than Linux will ever have, secondly OEMs make sure BIOS'es are correct for Windows. Barely any OEM tests their products compatibility against Linux. Lastly, the Ryzen 7000 platform is so new, there have been numerous bugs fixed in it lately.

Comment: oh sorry, I somehow missed the version :p

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, BIOS updated to the latest version. Same behavior. Is there a way to understand what happens without use a trial approach?

Comment: Does it respond to `ping`/`ssh`? If it doesn't it'll be extremely difficult to debug. If you can SSH in, you could run `dmesg` and see what's going on.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov good hint! Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

From the errors in dmesg: NVIDIA drivers have physically "lost" your GPU. It's no longer in your Linux system.

The errors could indicate your GPU is failing one way or another.

1. Try to reseat it (remove it and put it back firmly without applying too much pressure)
2. Try to replace your PSU with a beefier model
3. Make sure the power cable to your GPU is firmly seated in its connector
4. Make sure its fans are spinning - seeing `nvidia-smi` text output would be nice
5. Try running OCCT in Windows (GPU/PSU tests)
6. Lastly make sure you're running the latest Linux drivers (that's version 530.41.03 at the time of writing).

Comment: As already reported in the question, I don't think the issue is related to the hardware (psu, connector, etc...). Otherwise it would hangs anytime (not only the *first* boot), anywhere (in Windows as well).

Comment: Of course, if I'm wrong and there are evidences that can justify such a behavior I would go deeper on the hardware.

Comment: Linux and Windows do **not** work exactly the same with HW, so there could be differences in stability. UEFI, ACPI, ASPM even PCIe have a ton of things to set up differently. Lastly Windows has WHQL and Linux relies on companies and individuals doing their job. Unfortunately this results in Linux being less stable than Windows.

Comment: That's *exactly* my point (please, I'm just trying to understand. I'm not criticizing your answer). "Linux and Windows do not work exactly the same with HW" means the differences are in software rather in the HW - by definition, we're assuming the *same* HW.

Comment: Hence, there must be some software settings that could improve the stability without wasting the HW...

Comment: 1. The nvidia Linux driver allows to disable power saving modes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/232572/how-to-get-rid-of-nvidia-powermizer OR https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061919/set-max-power-level-of-nvidia-powermizer-to-1 2. You can disable ASPM for your entire PC in Linux though it could result in a higher idle power consumption, add `pcie_aspm=off` to your kernel boot options. I cannot vouch that any of these options will work. The issue could be something else entirely, e.g. your PSU. There's no guarantee spike loads are the same between Linux and Windows.

Comment: I said I was just trying to understand. I'm not used to go with random trials to debug a repeatable issue. And I was just pointing out that if there is a PSU problem (say) it should trigger anytime, not only at the first boot. But you didn't answer how it can trigger a hang only once.

Comment: Tried the `pcie_aspm=off` and unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Please try your luck here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @Mark Have you managed to resolve the issue? If you have, how?

Comment: Not yet, I'll come back when I've an update. Thanks for your effort!